# Cannot mount RAID 5 disks

Tags: mount, raid5

I am trying to mount 3 x 2TB RAID discs from an ubuntu server, but I cannot. I know that these disks were used in a server using RAID5. I tried to mount them using `mount -t` but I was unable to specify the filesystem.

[image: parted -l]

Comment: Please do note use images just to show text, paste the text instead.

Comment: please show the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`.  do not post a screenshot, copy-paste the text (and while you're at it, replace your screenshot with the text of `parted -l`.  also, edit your question and add the requested output, do not post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I am not quite sure that you are fully aware of what you are asking for.

If the disks are in RAID 5 how would you expect to mount them?

The RAID 5 system will unify the 3 disks into 1 virtual disk and that is the only disk that you will be able to mount. RAID is nothing but chunk of disks put together.....you can't mount the disks individually that are in a raid

Most importantly, what kind of raid 5 we are talking about here, software/hardware?

If you are referring to software pls follow the instructions in the following guide to set up a proper raid configuration (if that is what you are looking for):

```
   http://www.tecmint.com/create-raid-5-in-linux/
```

Alternatively, explain yourself better with some more data/info to allow us to help (you have to realize that we don't have the console to your system:-))